# Get unicode chars from webservice and display them in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I need some help:

i get from WebService only a part from the uunicode value, and after this I append the prefix \u to finish the value. The .ttf is good, i tested with some hardcoded values.

```
 NSString *cuvant = [[self.catData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:9]; //Get data 
//apend prefix (double \ to escape the \u command)
cuvant = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\u%@",cuvant]; 


// cell.catChar.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\ue674"]; --->this works very well
cell.catChar.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cuvant UTF8String]]; //---> this doesn't work
```

i searched the documentation, and other sites but i didn't found nothing usefull, all the hints are with hardcoded data... i need tot take the codes dinamically

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is just to feed this unicoded string as data first. So make a C-String then

`NSData *dataFromUnicodedString = [NSData dataWithBytes:yourCUnicodedString length:strlen(yourCUnicodedString)];`

and afterwards the resulting string will be

`NSString *unicodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataFromUnicodedString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: Or `NSString *s = @(cString);`.

Comment: thank you very much! i fixed it with this
NSString *cuvant = @"e674";
   cuvant = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\u%@", cuvant];
   
   
   NSLog(@"cuvant: %s", [cuvant UTF8String]);
   
//    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\ue674"];
   NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cuvant UTF8String]];
   
   NSData *data2 = [cuvant dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSString *decodevalue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data2 encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];